# Need help implementing google maps api for angular 7 app

Tags: typescript, google-maps-api-3, angular7, google-places-api

I'm trying to incorporate the google maps places api in my angular 7 app as a directive so whichever template element it is included in gets google map's address autocomplete suggestions.  Here's the code for my directive:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef, ContentChildren } from '@angular/core';
import {} from 'googlemaps';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appGoogleMaps]'
})
export class GoogleMapsDirective implements OnInit {

  autocomplete: any;

  constructor(private elem: ElementRef) {}

  @ContentChildren("formControl") varInputBoxes;

  ngOnInit(){
    this.initAutocomplete();
  }

  initAutocomplete(){
    let googleMapsOptions = {types: ['address']};
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.elem.nativeElement, googleMapsOptions);
    this.autocomplete.setFields(['geometry']);
    this.autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', this.getInfo);
  }

  getInfo(){
    let info = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
  }
}
```

In my index.html file, I've included the following code:

```
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=MY_API_KEY"></!--script>
</body>
```

Then I include "appGoogleMaps" in my address search input box in the template.  When I click into the input box and begin typing, google maps begins to suggest matching addresses as expected.  However, when I click on an address, I get the following error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getPlace' of undefined.  I am out of tricks on how to resolve this and my research on this topic hasn't helped at all.  I don't understand why suddenly "this.autocomplete" becomes undefined inside function getInfo.  Appreciate some help.

Comment: The problem is, API is running outside the NgZone. Check this answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352048/ionic3-angular4-two-way-databinding-stops-working-after-click-event-on-google-m/47352661#47352661

Comment: @Joe, I've never used ngZone.  WOuld you mind showing me how to use it in this case, considering I'm implementing the maps api as a directive as opposed to using it directly in a component?

Comment: You can see the sample code in the above link.

Comment: Implemented ngZone.run and that appears to resolve the issue.  That said, I still don't understand why ngZone is required with the google maps api or any other api for that matter.  Is that because these apis run in a zone outside of the angular zone and it's essential to bring their results back into the angular zone?  Please don't mind the plain English speak - I don't know all the jargon yet and am trying to understand this from a high level perspective.

Comment: Glad you resolved the issue. Yes, you are right. Google Map API is running outside the Angular zone and we need to bring the results to Angular zone.